# Is stoping or terminating ec2 instance does affect RDS created for instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Previously I have my Java project on aws but due to some financial reason I move project onto digital ocean instance , now I want to stop/terminate those (dev & prod) instances from aws console .Problem is we using RDS for the project so if I stop/terminate the ec2 instance it affect my database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDS instances are DB Architectures and are totally different instances than AWS EC2. RDS are independent of any EC2 , rather you can use RDS as the DB and host your Compute Engine in GCP or Azure and link them both together.

Networking is a main issue here, and you need to describe and put them in correct VPC Configuration and subnets, so that its not globally accesible.

Coming to your question, no RDS won't be terminated just because you terminate the EC2, it will keep running until and unless you explicitly terminate it.

Comment: @Atul , i need your help. Are you using RDS as external hive metastore in your project?

Comment: @Atul please accept as correct if I could solve your doubt

Comment: @SoumyajitDutta once i try this if everything works fine ...defenitly i accept your answer .... actually i move to different work now.